# C++ command pattern

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement something like a command pattern to control serveral components with the same interface. Every component must implement the following interface.

```
class ComponentInterface {
    public:
        virtual int start() = 0;
        virtual int stop()  = 0;
};
```

Every derived component will implement some specific methods.

```
class Led : public ComponentInterface {

    public:
        /**
         * Implements Interface methods
         */
        int start() { return 0; }
        int stop()  { return 0; }

    private:
        int setIntensity(int attrs[], int returns[]) {
            printf( "Set intensity called" );
            return 1;
        }

};
```

The main idea is that every subclass store the callable member functions in an array of pointers and in the `ComponentInterface` class will be implemented a methods that can call this functions based on the index of the command.

```
class ComponentInterface {
    public:
        ...
        // for storing the pointers
        int (ComponentInterface::*commandsArray[10])(int[], int[]);
        // to call the member functions
        int command(int commandId, int attrsList[], int responseList[]) {
            return (this->*commandsArray[commandId])(attrsList, responseList);
        }
}

class Led : public ComponentInterface {

    public:
        Led(float* ledIntensity) {
            // store the command in the array
            this->commandsArray[0] = (&Led::setIntensity);
         }

        // redefine the array for pointers of this subclass
        int (Led::*commandsArray[5])(int[], int[]);

};
```

I'm not familiar with C++ and I don't understand why it doesn't work, I have problems when calling the stored functions.

When testing with devC++, I get a segmentation fault. When i tried to test it in Visual Studio 2013 (Visual C++) and with the debugger it seems that in this row

```
(this->*commandsArray[commandId])(attrsList, responseList);
```

, the `this` object is pointing to the ComponentInterface object instead of the Led object.

Comment: "I have problems" is essentially useless - what problems do you have exactly? What are the compiler or runtime errors you're getting?

Comment: @Mat - I'm testing it with `devC++` and I become a `segmentation fault`

Comment: Segfault where? Use a debugger to find out. Then investigate and add what you found to your question.

Comment: @Mat - in this row `(this->*commandsArray[commandId])(attrsList, responseList);`, i tried to test it in Visual Studio 2013 (Visual C++) and with the debugger it seems that the `this` object is pointing to the `ComponentInterface` object instead of the `Led` object

Comment: Add the details to your question, not in the comments.

Comment: `// redefine the array for pointers of this subclass` - you're storing a pointer in one array, then using a (presumably invalid) pointer from another. Either find some way to use the right array from the base class, or use `std::function` to allow storage of different function types in the same container.

Comment: Does that even compile? `this->commandsArray[0] = static_cast<int (ComponentInterface::*)(int*,int*)>(&Led::setIntensity);` should work, but your code seems wrong

Comment: @MarcoA. - with the `static_cast` and removing the `int (Led::*commandsArray[5])(int[], int[]);` it works, thank you :-)

Comment: @MikeSeymour - when I call the `command` function of the base class it will not be used the `commandsArray` from the led class?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik: No, only the array in the base class is in scope within the base class. You can't "override" member variables in C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - So the base class functions are not called in the derived class scope, but remain in the base scope, but every sub class has it's own commandsArray? or it's shared with other subclasses? (I come from javascript)

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik: Indeed, every member function is in the scope of its own class. The base class contains an array; in your example, the derived class contains a separate array of a different type, in addition to the one it inherits from the base class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - if i would use the `std::function` pointers I will maintain the `this` pointer right? or I would lose it?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik: You'd bind `this` to the function. The function type would be `function<int(int*,int*)>`, storing something like `bind(&Led::setIntensity, this, _1, _2)` or `[this](int*a,int*r){setIntensity(a,r);}`.

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d494c986a1f9878

Answer (score 2):

Two things are immediately wrong in your code:

1. You can't "*override a base class variable*" and this line doesn't quite make sense in your derived class

   ```
   // redefine the array for pointers of this subclass
   int (Led::*commandsArray[5])(int[], int[]);
   ```
2. This cast is wrong

   ```
   this->commandsArray[0] = (&Led::setIntensity);
   ```

   it should rather be

   ```
   this->commandsArray[0] = static_cast<int (ComponentInterface::*)(int*,int*)>(&Led::setIntensity);
   ```

Anyway a cleaner and safer way to achieve what you want is the following:

<sub>(Disclaimer: heavy stripping ahead, ignoring everything that doesn't immediately matter in the discussion)</sub>

```
class ComponentInterface {
  ..
  std::vector<std::function<int (int[], int[])>> commandsArray;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/P6SnFu)</kbd>

You could then store member functions with different signatures (bound to the right object) and just use the ComponentInterface container in your components.